# PassportJS + Freshbooks - OAuth errors

Tags: oauth, passport.js

I'd like to use PassportJS with Freshbooks.com.

Freshbooks uses OAuth 1.0a, so I copied over the passport-linkedin repo and attempted to convert it to Freshbooks.

I'm getting an error I don't understand:

```
failed to obtain request token (status: 400 data: Unsupported signature method specified.)
```

Is there a debug switch for Passport?  I also put together another version using just the OAuthStrategy and I'm getting the same error.

The Freshbooks OAuth API is here: http://developers.freshbooks.com/authentication-2/#OAuth

To run the example server in the module:

```
git clone git@github.com:MichaelJCole/passport-freshbooks.git
npm install
npm install passport express ejs passport-oauth  
node example/login/app.js
```

The stack trace:

```
failed to obtain request token (status: 400 data: Unsupported signature method specified.)
    at /home/michaelcole/scm/passport-freshbooks/node_modules/passport-oauth/lib/passport-oauth/strategies/oauth.js:196:36
    at /home/michaelcole/scm/passport-freshbooks/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:518:17
    at passBackControl (/home/michaelcole/scm/passport-freshbooks/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:374:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/michaelcole/scm/passport-freshbooks/node_modules/passport-oauth/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:386:9)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:910:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this looks like it happened because the server wanted PLAINTEXT encoding vs HMAC-SHA1

The solution was to update the strategy to include signatureMethod

```
function Strategy(options, verify) {
  options = options || {};
  options.requestTokenURL = 'https://' + options.serverName + '/oauth/oauth_request.php';
  options.accessTokenURL = 'https://' + options.serverName + '/oauth/oauth_access.php';
  options.userAuthorizationURL = 'https://' + options.serverName + '/oauth/oauth_authorize.php';
  options.signatureMethod = "PLAINTEXT";  // < ------------------------ HERE
  options.sessionKey = options.sessionKey || 'oauth:freshbooks';

  console.log(options.requestTokenURL);
```